# composer ssl certificate error in xampp 5.6 in centos

Tags: php, ssl, centos, xampp, composer-php

I just installed xampp 5.6 and composer in my centos, but when i try to update composer "composer self-update" in gives me error like this

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: SSL ope  
  ration failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:                           
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify   
  failed                                                                       
  Failed to enable crypto                                                      
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

i googled and its tell me that openssl certificate is expired or can't find the cert.pem, i generate new certificate and place into path but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

find the CA file I ran this command

> locate cacert.pem

Result was:
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem

Then open the php.ini file and
change this:

;openssl.cafile=
To this:

openssl.cafile=/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem
Note: This directive is only available on php 5.6.x

Then restart Apache

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer this post, but i m using latest version of xampp and there isnt any result like "/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem" however i am using xampp there is  "/opt/lampp/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/" directory but not Mozilla directory

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution as @ammarali29 suggest, instead of using "/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem" i used "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/cacert.pem" which was the result of

```
locate cacert.pem
```

and done accordingly @ammarali29 suggested, its worked

Thank you @ammarali29